# Changing directory with bash script issue

Tags: linux, bash

I'm in the early stages of creating a bash script and running into an issue. I want the script to take user input and change into the directory the user specified. I add "source" or . in front of the script name and it takes me to the correct directory. The issue is when I try to change into a sub directory  of the directory i just changed into for some reason my ssh connection gets disconnected. I've never had this issue before so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it.

The output of echo "$-" is himBHs.

Comment: make sure you don't have `set -e` for your login shell.

Comment: I dont think it is set but how would i confirm. Would the login shell settings be in one of the bash or profile files?

Comment: Do `echo "$-"` and see if the answer contains `e` -- if it does, one of your startup files adds that setting.

Comment: I ran the command you suggested and there was no 'e';

Comment: Then I don't know why the remote shell exits. You could try turning on tracing in the remote with `set -x` and see if there's any other commands that execute when you change directory.

Comment: Once changed into the directory I can run ls -lt or pwd and they work. When trying to change into a sub directory it will kill the ssh session.

Comment: Did the set -x output give you any clues? You could paste that into your question. Your sequence will be: `ssh user@host`, `set -x`, `cd dir`, `ls -ldF subdir`, `cd subdir`

Comment: I've added the output to the original post. I've followed your sequence and added it to my script. Now although it doesn't exit , it is not actually changing directories.

Comment: Actually following your steps worked for me and my session is no longer being terminated. Thank you for your guidance.